# password expire duration and maximum invalid login attempts

Tags: cassandra

how to set password expire duration and maximum invalid login attempts for user under Cassandra DB ?

for example user test tried to login with incorrect password 5 times , that should should get blocked or write this info to logs.

password expire duration  how we can configure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra has pluggable authentication. You can write your own authenticator class that achieves what you want. That's a bit of work, yet it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra doesn't have such functionality (yet). In [DSE you can enable audit logs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/sec/auditEnabling.html), and log all authentication attempts & their result - but I don't remember such functionality for Cassandra